# Previously Rooted Nexus 5 is not recognized via USB after stock 5.0 OTA update

Tags: rooting, root-access, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

I have a previously rooted Nexus 5 on 4.4 and updated it recently with the Lollipop OTA. I am trying to re-root it again but it is not recognized using my Windows 7, Windows 8 or Ubuntu 14.04 machines. I have tried the WUG toolkit on windows by installing and reinstalling the drivers and adb on linux, turning on/off the Developer-usb-debugging mode, turning on-off the MTP mode. I was previously using TWRP. Now when I go to recovery mode, the phone shows "No command" with the green droid.

Comment: "No command" in recovery mode isn't an error; that's just what the stock recovery looks like when you boot it directly (rather than as part of an update).

Comment: In lollipop when you enable the USB debugging, you will get a pop up on you mobile to allow the USB connection to your device. Did you get this popup after enabling USB debugging? Is the Nexus 5 device detected under you device manager?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is issue of USB connector. Most of the times due to dust it does not get proper contacts on USB pins and its not recognized over USB. Try to check that.